# Getting Megabytes per Second in Powershell (mostly a casting question)

Tags: powershell, casting, exchange-server, powershell-2.0

What is the correct way to do cast an `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.EnhancedTimeSpan` and `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize` into seconds and bytes (or megs) respectively so that I can divide them?

```
function Get-MBStats($Username = "someuser")
{

$UserDetail = (Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $Username  -IncludeMoveHistory).MoveHistory[0] 
# | ft  status, targetdatabase , completiontimestamp , totalmailboxsize ,overallduration -auto#

# What is the syntax for this?
$DataRate =  $UserDetail.OverallDuration / $UserDetail.TotalMailboxSize

New-Object PSObject -Property @{
Username = $Username
Status = $UserDetail.Status
TargetDatabase = $UserDetail.TargetDatabase
CompletionTime = $UserDetail.CompletionTimestamp
TotalMailboxSize = $UserDetail.TotalMailboxSize
OverallDuration = $UserDetail.OverallDuration
Rate = $DataRate
}

# Todo: GUI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288074.aspx #
}

Get-MBStats
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that I can discover the members of the type by doing this

`$a.TotalItemSize.Value | Get-Member`

Where $a represents the variable of the type I'm working with.

Here is the members of ByteQuantifiedSize

```
   TypeName: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize

Name          MemberType Definition
----          ---------- ----------
CompareTo     Method     int CompareTo(Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize other)
Equals        Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize other)
GetHashCode   Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType       Method     type GetType()
RoundUpToUnit Method     System.UInt64 RoundUpToUnit(Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize+Quantifier quantifier)
ToBytes       Method     System.UInt64 ToBytes()
ToGB          Method     System.UInt64 ToGB()
ToKB          Method     System.UInt64 ToKB()
ToMB          Method     System.UInt64 ToMB()
ToString      Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string format), string ToString(string format, System.IF...
ToTB          Method     System.UInt64 ToTB()
```

And here are the members for EnhancedTimeSpan.

```
   TypeName: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.EnhancedTimeSpan

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
Add               Method     Microsoft.Exchange.Data.EnhancedTimeSpan Add(System.TimeSpan ts)
CompareTo         Method     int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(Microsoft.Exchange.Data.EnhancedTimeS...
Divide            Method     long Divide(System.TimeSpan ts)
Duration          Method     Microsoft.Exchange.Data.EnhancedTimeSpan Duration()
Equals            Method     bool Equals(System.Object value), bool Equals(Microsoft.Exchange.Data.EnhancedTimeSpan ...
GetHashCode       Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType           Method     type GetType()
Mod               Method     Microsoft.Exchange.Data.EnhancedTimeSpan Mod(System.TimeSpan ts)
Multiply          Method     Microsoft.Exchange.Data.EnhancedTimeSpan Multiply(long n)
Negate            Method     Microsoft.Exchange.Data.EnhancedTimeSpan Negate()
Subtract          Method     Microsoft.Exchange.Data.EnhancedTimeSpan Subtract(System.TimeSpan ts)
ToString          Method     string ToString()
Days              Property   System.Int32 Days {get;}
Hours             Property   System.Int32 Hours {get;}
Milliseconds      Property   System.Int32 Milliseconds {get;}
Minutes           Property   System.Int32 Minutes {get;}
Seconds           Property   System.Int32 Seconds {get;}
Sign              Property   System.Int32 Sign {get;}
Ticks             Property   System.Int64 Ticks {get;}
TotalDays         Property   System.Double TotalDays {get;}
TotalHours        Property   System.Double TotalHours {get;}
TotalMilliseconds Property   System.Double TotalMilliseconds {get;}
TotalMinutes      Property   System.Double TotalMinutes {get;}
TotalSeconds      Property   System.Double TotalSeconds {get;}
```